# How to use file upload to upload image file into server in html using javascript by webservice

Tags: javascript, html

I unable to upload image file in html, I try to use html file tag but not work proper.Give me help urgent.i call web service for registration through ajax request and web service is created using C#.net. and we want to upload image and save it into server through request

Comment: you can't upload file to server using javascript alone, where is your server side code? which technology you are using?

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a form with enctype = "multipart/form-data" And when the form is posted, request for the data on server..

```
<form action="upload_file.php" method="post"
enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label for="file">Filename:</label>
<input type="file" name="file" id="file"><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
```